# is there not a case statment in C programming, not switch case btw

Tags: c, switch-statement

I maybe doing this using the wrong method. But I am just trying to exercise my brain a little using C programming. Tasking myself with writing a "yahtzee" like command line game learning whatever that leads me to have to learn in order to get it done.

I do know that there is such a thing called a "case statement". But every time I google it. I keep getting the  "switch case statement" instead.

Putting me in doubt that C even has a **case statement**.

All I am trying to do at this moment it call the same function 5 times and put each different return value into a separate variable. Then print out each variables value using a drop down case statement breaking out of the last one.

But it is seems it is not calling the function as it drops through the switch. As I cannot seem to find the properly way to write a case statement in C and not the switch - case.

so correct me if I am wrong but would not a case statement execute the commands whereas it seems that the switch is not.

It is not a lot of code here, so I am going to post it in its entirely. So you can see what it is I am really doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randon_number(int min_num, int max_num);

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{


  int i =0, die1 = 0, die2 = 0, die3 = 0, die4 = 0, die5 = 0, num = 0;

  switch (i) {
   case 1:
     die1=randon_number(1,6);
   case 2:
     die2=randon_number(1,6);
   case 3:
     die3=randon_number(1,6);
   case 4:
     die4=randon_number(1,6);
   case 5:
     die5=randon_number(1,6);
     break;
 }
// checking just to make sure that it is working written like this.
  num=randon_number(1,6);

  printf("this is num %d\n\n", num);

  printf("d1 %d d2 %d d3 %d d4 %d d5 %d\n", die1, die2, die3, die4, die5);

 return 0;
}

int randon_number(int min_num, int max_num)
{
  int result = 0, low_num = 0, hi_num = 0;

  if (min_num < max_num)
  {
    low_num = min_num;
    hi_num = max_num + 1; // include max_num in output
  } else {
    low_num = max_num + 1; //include max_num in output
    hi_num = min_num;
  }

  srand(time(NULL));
  result = (rand() % (hi_num - low_num)) + low_num;
  return result;
  }
```

everything in the switch gets a zero returned. I do think that a case acually executes the command, would or should not the switch do the same?

even though I am looking for the case statement. I got tired of the peck and hunt method, that is why I posted this question.

```
 case (i) {
    1;
     num=randon_number(1,6);
    2;
      printf("this is num %d\n\n", num);
      break;
  }
```

or any other variation I've tried does not work.

This is a BASH case statement that actually calls the function more than once  and gets a proper return value for each variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

rannum (){
  number=$((RANDOM%3))

 return $number
 }


var=1

case $var  in 

1)
  {
   rannum
   num1=$number
   rannum
   num2=$number
   }
   ;;
 2)
  {
  num1=rannum
  }
  ;;
  esac

 printf "$num1 - $num2\n"
```

Comment: There is no `case` statement in C.  There are `case` labels which may appear in the body of a `switch` statement, but that's it.  And you probably need to use `break;` to stop the flow from continuing past the end of the code associated with a `case` label.

Comment: the code you show will do nothing in the switch block, it sets i = 0 then does a switch with cases 1-6

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  then would that not defeat the purpose of getting it called 5 times in a roll because after it called it once it will break out of the entire switch statement leaving me with still having to call it 4 more times?

Comment: If you just want to call five times in a row, then why do you need a switch-case at all?

Comment: @pm100 ugh - got a rethink this then it looks like from yours and that others guys reply.

Comment: are you expecting i to get incremented ; that switch is somehow a loop. It is not. It is a conditional execute, it can be replaced by a series of if and else statements, but sometimes switch makes the intent clearer

Comment: Why do you expect C to have such a syntax you assume? Different languages have different syntax and constructs. Did you do **any** research about `switch ... case` in C? Does not look like you did. A simple google search shows various tutorials how to use this construct properly. A C bokk will do the same.

Comment: @GoodDeeds the effect of it that it just runs down the line and suppose to just call it fives times because no break is in there. beats having to write the same line file times. calling the function, even though I still had to. gerp. just run time thinking. I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The `case` keyword in C is not a statement; it produces labels, and is only valid within the context of a `switch` statement. So yes, your Googling is correct: switch/case is it. Not sure what else you were expecting or why.

Also note the several restrictions on `case`: only integer values, and you must explicitly terminate with `break`.

Answer (score 0):

The execution inside a `switch` statement is not limited to a pseudo-block limited by`case` labels.

You need to inform the compiler to get out of the `switch` statement at the end of each case (if that is really what you want) with `break` statement

```
switch (x) {
    default: printf("--"); break;
    case 1: printf("1"); break;
    case 2: case 3: printf("23"); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the syntax of `switch` slightly wrong. Take this example

```
switch(i)
  {
case 1:
  printf("1\n");
case 2:
  printf("2\n");
break;
case 3:
  printf("3\n");
break;
default:
  printf("?\n");
break;
  }
```

if `i` is 1 then it outputs 1, but because that case doesn't end with a break, it continues on to the next case and also prints out 2. If however `i` is 3, then it just prints out 3 as there is a break at the end of the case label. If it doesn't match any of the cases, it does the `default` instead and prints out a question mark.

Your first switch statement wouldn't match any of the cases as `i` is 0. If you're trying to populate all of the `die{number}` variables you probably just want to do them one at a time like this:

```
die1=randon_number(1,6);
die2=randon_number(1,6);
die3=randon_number(1,6);
```

Comment: so basically it is working like a case statement that I am familiar with. if the **case (var) in** matches any of the selections after it  **1) -  2) etc ...** then it will use that one to execute the command(s) that matches the var. It is just being written differently. back to the drawing board. thanks.

Comment: well it's not matching the ones after it...it's just that the code isn't `break`ing out of the case it does match so will do the ones afterwards

Comment: I'll figure it out. I too need to think at least three steps ahead of this so I will not have to rewrite everything.

Comment: OK I made i=1 put the function call in case 1 five times and get a return of value 1 for each one of them. d1 1 d2 1 d3 1 d4 1 d5 1 .

Comment: I will figure something out to get this programming working.  **I've only just begun**

Comment: OK I put a printf statement inside of the function and it is getting called as many times as I tell it to, (just checking) and the function is always returning that very same value.. that is the problem not the switch.

Comment: You'll be getting the same number as you're resetting the random seed with every call to the same seed. You shouldn't need to call `srand` more than once - just put it into main before you do anything else and `rand` will return different values.

Comment: @ChrisTuner  thanks I've been messing this that rand for a bit now and  kind of not liking rand as random is not random.